# Is there a JavaScript library for validating P2SH addresses?

Tags: multi-signature, p2sh

I looked at [coinstring.js](http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/currency/coinstring/) but it looks like it only validates simple BTC addresses (`1`-prepended addresses).

> #### isValid(base58str, version)
>
> Validates whether the address string or wallet import format string is valid.
>
> `base58str`: A `string` that is either the wallet import format or public address.
>
> `version`: Is an integer representing the version or `Buffer`. See below for more information.
>
> Returns a `true` or `false`.

I'm looking for a JS library that can validate BIP16 [P2SH](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pay_to_script_hash) addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library you've linked.

Instead of using:

```
isValid(address, 0)
```

use

```
isValid(address, 5)
```